# Split Word Document and Save as (.RTF)

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have [this VBA code](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/word/966-word-split-documents-into-multiple-documents.html) which split word document into multiple documents by the splitter (///),

```
Sub SplitNotes(delim As String, strFilename As String)
Dim doc As Document
Dim arrNotes
Dim I As Long
Dim X As Long
Dim Response As Integer
arrNotes = Split(ActiveDocument.Range, delim)
Response = MsgBox("This will split the document into " & UBound(arrNotes) + 1 & " sections.Do you wish to proceed?", 4)
If Response = 7 Then Exit Sub
For I = LBound(arrNotes) To UBound(arrNotes)
If Trim(arrNotes(I)) <> "" Then
X = X + 1
Set doc = Documents.Add
doc.Range = arrNotes(I)
doc.SaveAs ThisDocument.Path & "\" & strFilename & Format(X, "000")
doc.Close True
End If
Next I
End Sub
Sub test()
'delimiter & filename
SplitNotes "///", "Notes "
End Sub
```

this saves the splitted docs to (.Docx), How can I save them into (.Rtf) instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `wdFormatRTF` to save as RTF format, i.e.

```
doc.SaveAs2 ThisDocument.Path & "\" & strFilename & Format(X, "000"), FileFormat:=wdFormatRTF
```

Comment: @AbuElhaytham Glad it helps you, could you please accept the answer if it works for you?